# Как получить диапазон значений в массиве?

Tags: javascript

К примеру имеем такой массив :

```
var num = [100 ,190 ,200 ,210 ,220 ,230 ,360 ,300 ,340 ,500 ,570 ,590];
```

я хочу получить значения больше 200 но меньше 500

я это (провально) делал так

```
num.map(function(x){
  if(x > 220 || x < 500){
     var arr = [x];
     console.log(arr)
  }
})
```

но появлялись все цифры из массива

как можно фильтровать массив в диапазоне каких то величин ?

Comment: [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) же. Ну и лучше ставить скобки в условии

Comment: @Grundy при этом условии сработает ?

Comment: попробуй :) :) :)

Comment: @Grundy от 100 до 590 всё вышло

Comment: куда вышло? как проверял?

Comment: Ну и собственно `||` - это **ИЛИ**, а ты хочешь **И**

Comment: @Grundy а что ты молчал тогда ...видел же ошибку в логических выражениях ?

Comment: я не сразу заметил :-) через 10 минут после первого комментария ток

Comment: @Grundy  а нельзя ли удалить этот аккаунт или объединить с  действующим ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact здесь есть подходящий пункт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так)

```js
var num = [100,190,200,210,220,230,360,300,340,500,570,590];
    for (i=0;i<num.length;i++){
      if (num[i]>200 && num[i]<500)
        console.log(num[i]);
    }
```

А выводятся все числа потому, что вы используете if(x > 220 || x < 500)
так вы говорите что  (число больше 220 или меньше 500), получается например число 20 меньше 500, поэтому проходит условие.

```js
var num = [100 ,190 ,200 ,210 ,220 ,230 ,360 ,300 ,340 ,500 ,570 ,590];
num.map(function(x){
    if(x > 220 && x < 500){
     var arr = [x];
     console.log(arr)
  }
})
```

Comment: добавь описание чем твой код отличается от кода в вопросе, и почему это решение работает, а код из вопроса - нет

Comment: амперсанд ...е маё

Answer (score 5):

В Вашем примере присутствует логическая ошибка в условии. Согласно задаче число должно удовлетворять следующему условию: быть больше 200 **и** меньше 500, а Вы указали логическое `или`. Поэтому все числа, которые больше 200 **или** меньше 500, т.е. все, соответствовали установленному фильтру.
Если перейти к решению, то у массива существует метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). На Вашем конкретном примере использование может выглядеть так:

```js
var num = [100,190,200,210,220,230,360,300,340,500,570,590];
var filtered = num.filter(n => n > 200 && n < 500);
// или
// var filtered = num.filter(function(n) {
//                    return n > 200 && n < 500;
//                });
console.log(filtered);
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Array​.prototype​.filter() на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [полифил для filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill)
- [поддержка filter браузерами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: простите что выбрал не ваш ответ решением но мне до es6 как до пекина в умной позе :))

Comment: @MaximLensky ничего страшного (только причём здесь ES6?) :) Но будет хорошо, если в следующий раз при написании вопросы Вы будете как можно точнее описывать условия, ограничения и другие вещи относящиеся к проблеме.

Comment: понял спасибо..

Comment: @XelaNimed ES6 тут, видимо, из-за стрелочных функций :)